# What does a "heat ball" look like?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I am learning Mean value property (MVP) of the heat equation. MVP of Laplace equation was relatively easy to understand I think it is because of the spherical symmetry. But I am not able to appreciate the MVP of heat equation. It's not very easy to imagine the "heat ball" in the following theorem from a [note](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/527.1.08f/lec13.pdf):

> [image]

Here are **questions**:

> - How do I define a heat ball?
> - How does it actually look like?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @LeonidKovalev : My question is how do i define a heat ball ? And how does it actually look like ?

Comment: Could you give a reference to a text you are reading?

Comment: @abatkai : I have added the reference . Thank you

Answer (score 9):

The "heat ball" is defined as it is in the note you cited which is bases on Evans's *[Partial Differential Equations](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-19-r)* Chapter 2.3.

For fixed $x\in{\bf R}^n$, $t\in{\bf R}$ and $r>0$, we define
$$
E(x,t;r)=\left\{(y,s)\in {\bf R}^{n+1}\bigg|\; s\leqslant t,\ \dfrac{1}{(4\pi(t-s))^{n/2}}\exp\left({-\dfrac{|x-y|^2}{4(t-s)}}\right)\geqslant\frac{1}{r^n}\right\}.
$$

The Wikipedia article [Mean-value property for the heat equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation#Mean-value_property_for_the_heat_equation) also gives a similar definition.

---

Note that in the definition, one should replace $s\leqslant t$ with $s<t$. To get some ideas of what such "ball" would look like, consider $n=1$ and 
$$
E(0,0;1)=\left\{(y,s)\in {\bf R}^{2}\bigg|\; s<0,\ \dfrac{1}{(4\pi(-s))^{1/2}}\exp\left({-\dfrac{|-y|^2}{4(-s)}}\right)\geqslant 1\right\}\\
=\left\{(y,s)\in{\bf R}^2\bigg|\; 0<-s\leqslant\frac{1}{4\pi}, y^2\leq 2s\log(-4\pi s)\right\}
$$
To get $-s\leqslant\frac{1}{4\pi}$ one can simply observe that $\exp\left(-\dfrac{|-y|^2}{4(-s)}\right)\leqslant 1$ for $s<0$ and thus
$$
\sqrt{-4\pi s}\leqslant 1.
$$
On the other hand, taking the logarithm of 
$\dfrac{1}{(4\pi(-s))^{1/2}}\exp\left({-\dfrac{|-y|^2}{4(-s)}}\right)\geqslant 1$ gives
$$
y^2\leq 2s\log(-4\pi s).
$$

The boundary of the heat ball is like this:

[image]

Comment: How did you derive the expression for $E(0,0; 1)$? If you assume $t = 0$, shouldn't $s$ be less than $0$?

Comment: @el_tenedor: Thanks for pointing that out! That's certainly a mistake and I have now edited the answer.

Comment: I have just noticed that I'm responding to a comment about one year old.

Answer (score 2):

There is an illustration on page 53 of *PDE* by Evans. Nothing mysterious, just an ellipsoid-like shape with the "center" $(x,t)$ located at the center on the top boundary (not in the interior, as for elliptic PDE).

The definition is in the book you are reading, formula (23).

Comment: Sir, Why should it be ellipsoid ? Can you help me to understand it

Comment: @Theorem For each fixed value of time variable $s$, you get a two-dimensional slice which is a circle. The radius of the circle depends on $s$: it drops to zero when $s=t$ and when $s$ is much smaller than $t$.